# Fetching attachments from CXF generated stub

Tags: cxf, axis

We are migrating from AXIS1 to CXF and generating stub using the wsdltojava ANT utility provided by CXF. However we are unable to getattachments from a response of Webservicecall as these attachments are not directly embedded in the response. The earlier implementation was using the standard method getAttachments() of the AXIS api.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

Probably found the answer by now, but for anyone else the key is the service proxy can be cast to a `javax.xml.ws.Binding` and then you can get the `ResponseContext` (a map) and attachments via the `org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ATTACHMENTS` key:

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Attachment;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
...

Collection<Attachment> attachments = (Collection<Attachment>)
    ((BindingProvider)yourServiceProxy).getResponseContext()
        .get(Message.ATTACHMENTS);
for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
    // ID is in attachment.getId();
    // Data is in attachment.getDataHandler();

    // Eg:
    DataHandler data = attachment.getDataHandler();
    InputStream is = data.getInputStream();
    File dataFile = new File(data.getName());
    System.out.println("Writing data to:\n\t" + 
        dataFile.toString());     
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
    IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
    fos.close();   
}
```